# capturing url and loading that urls contents into the same or different div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Wanted to know if it is possible and if so where am i failing on capturing a url and displaying the contents of that file into a div on the same page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type='text/javascript' 
src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page"> 
<div data-role="header"></div> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <p id = "heading">Is Nursing For You?</p>
        <br/>
        <div id = "div1" align="center"></div>
    </div> 
<div data-role="footer" id = "foot" data-position="fixed">    
</div> 
</div> 
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#div1").load('FONWVhp.php', function() {
    $('#div1 div.center-wrapper a button').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        ($(this).parent().attr('href'));
        $("#div1").load(($(this).parent().attr('href'))'articles.php', 
        function() {

        });
    });
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

fonwvhp.php

index.html loads pages hrefs(which are pointed to articles.php?pageId...)once the page is clicked i want the href to load into the div1 tag and display the href results.

```
$sqlPAQuery = "SELECT pages.pageId, pages.pageTitle FROM pages order by 
pages.pageId";
$paqueryResult = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlPAQuery);

 while ($paqueryRow = mysqli_fetch_object($paqueryResult))
 {

 $pages = "<div class='center-wrapper'><a href = articles.php?
 pageId=".$paqueryRow->pageId."><button class= center-
 wrapper'>".$paqueryRow-
 >pageTitle."</button></a><br/><br/></div>";
 echo $pages;

 }
```

articles.php

this is the page i would like to be placed in div1 tag after page href is clicked

```
$sqlARTICLEQuery = "SELECT * FROM articles where pageId=".$_GET['pageId']." 
order by articleId";

$articlequeryResult = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlARTICLEQuery);
while ($articlequeryRow = mysqli_fetch_object($articlequeryResult))
{
$articles ="<div id = 'div1' class='center-wrapper'><a href = article.php?
articleId=".$articlequeryRow->articleId."><button id 
='wrapper'>".$articlequeryRow->articleTitle."</button></a><br/><br/></div>";
echo $articles;
}
```

Comment: Please isolate and describe the problem in detail.  Does it capture or not? Is it the displaying that fails?  Answering these questions will help you to see what debugging steps you need to take before asking a question.  When you dump your code, take a step back and say "it doesn't work", then volunteers have to spend more time trying to diagnose the problem (or avoid your too broad question entirely).  Help us to help you.  What exactly works as expected and what doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess but most likely you forgot the `/` or you have the `)` in the wrong spot

Change

```
  $("#div1").load(($(this).parent().attr('href'))'articles.php'
```

To

```
  $("#div1").load(($(this).parent().attr('href')+'/articles.php')
```

Answer (score 0):

These 2 lines

```
($(this).parent().attr('href'));
$("#div1").load(($(this).parent().attr('href'))'articles.php',
```

The first line is useless.  Delete it.
The second line.  You're getting the href of the parent element to the button that was clicked in content loaded from FONWVhp.php (which you didn't post, by the way so I have to guess what it is).  To that you are trying but failing to append 'articles.php'.

```
// Delete me ($(this).parent().attr('href'));
$("#div1").load($(this).parent().attr('href') + 'articles.php',
```

Note that this will work fine as long as the href always ends in a slash.  If it doesn't, which might be likely (depending again on what the mysterious FONWVhp.php contains) then you will have to figure that out too (by putting a slash in, most likely).